# Matlab's GUI function execution in normal file

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, input

I have a *Matlab's GUI* that takes user input, the `GUI() function` have functions that performs the task regarding input and stores in *workspace-variables*, the question is, how can I use the function in my code so that when user enters input or input function returns its value, how can I command to run rest of the code automatically, i.e terminates *GUI function* or leaves it idle and performs normal execution? When I use the *GUI()* again, it again takes input and performs the task rest of my code.
Suggest me the ways to that the system waits for the input command from *Matlab's GUI* and and performs its task as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can uncomment a `uiwait(handles.figure1);` in the `OpeningFcn` (e.g. `testGUI_OpeningFcn`) to allow the GUI to wait for a user response and only return to the command prompt when it closes.

I'm not sure if I understood all of your question, but this seems to be an issue you are having.

Comment: All I need is after user response, it executes normally, i.e outside the rest code of function GUI.